# go unmarshal xml with attributes

Tags: xml, go

Having trouble getting xml to unmarshal so I can access xml attributes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point. It complies, but the struct doesn't appear to contain any data.

```
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)
```

contents of xml:

```
  <module id="Core" description="Core Module" tenantId="tenant1" major="3" minor="4" patch="0" build="0">
    <probePath path="bin" />
  </module>
</metadata>
```

```
type ModuleField struct {
    Id string `xml:"id,attr"`
    Description string `xml:"description,attr"`
    TenantId string `xml:"tenantId,attr"`
    Major string `xml:"major,attr"`
    Minor string `xml:"minor,attr"`
    Patch string `xml:"patch,attr"`
}

type Module struct {
    ModuleField ModuleField
    ProbePath string `xml:"probePath"`
}

type Metadata struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"metadata"`
    Module Module
}
```

```
// read xml file
    raw, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(XMLLoc)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }


    var XMLData Metadata 
    xml.Unmarshal(raw, &XMLData)

    // nothing is being printed
    fmt.Println(">",XMLData.Module.ModuleField.TenantId,"<")
```

Comment: All your attributes are on the `module` element, but the fields aren't on the `Module` type that you're using to represent that element, they're on another type that's set up as if you're expecting a `ModuleField` child element, which does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letter case matters, so the element `module` will not be unmarshaled into a field called `Module`, you need to add the proper tag. Also you'll need to embed the `ModuleField` into `Module` so that its fields are *promoted* to `Module` and only then they will be unmarshaled. Or, alternatively, you can remove `ModuleField` and move all its fields into `Module`.

https://play.golang.org/p/AvaEpcKY-oh

Comment: Hey, thank you, your answer really helped me understand.